# Validate numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

How can I validate only the numbers 0 to 10?

I have this function which validate all the numbers.

```
function compruebacampo(e, campotexto) {
 if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
   return false;
 }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/6faHh/

Comment: `n >= 0 && n <= 10` ?

Answer (score 1):

The best JavaScript is no JavaScript.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" />
```

Comment: It looks like you still have to perform validation "manually", since the user can enter numbers outside of the range. And while Firefox shows a red border around the input, it seem to consider the input as "invalid": http://jsfiddle.net/2ntps/ *edit:* nvm, `ele.validity.valid` is `false`. Still you have to do use some JS to check that property.

Comment: its not @niet, I don't think so

Comment: @FelixKling If you enter an invalid number, the form will not submit. I would add a demo but I'm on my phone.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Then at the risk of sounding blunt, you are wrong.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Nice. But if you want to work with the value in JS, you'd still have to "validate" it first (by checking `el.validity.valid`).

Comment: @FelixKling Unless you work with the value in a `submit` event handler, because the event won't fire if there are invalid fields ;) HTML5, it's magic!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="your_input_id1" type="number" min="0" max="10" />
<input id="your_input_id2" type="number" min="0" max="10" />
<script>
    var input1 = document.getElementById("your_input_id1");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("your_input_id2");


    function testNums(evt) {
        var num = parseInt(evt.target.value, 10);
        if (typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1) {
            evt.target.value = num
        } else {
            evt.target.value = ''
        }
    };
    input1.onkeyup = testNums;
    input2.onkeyup = testNums;
</script>
```

Example js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/g63b5/3/

In this example entry is prevented and the box is cleared if the range is incorrect or anything other than number entered, also uses native html5 input for supported devices.

Edit: wasn't 100% sure what your comment meant, so I just added the handler to more inputs, in case that is what you were asking.

Comment: thanks,this is nice,just a question,How can I use this for some inputs?

Comment: Hi eduardo, I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you simply asking how to attach this function to multiple inputs? Did you click the fiddle?